# cURL got different page source than what Chrome browser did

Tags: bash, google-chrome, curl, cloudflare

In short: I'm trying to get that page source of https://www.etoro.com/app/sv-iframe using curl in Bash.

I understand this ask is quite "simple". I have read thru 10+ similar questions here. Unfortunately, none of them could solve my problem.

When you open the URL above in Chrome browser, it's blank. You can either right click -> View Page Source, or sniff network using Chrome Developer Tool. Both will give you the correct page source. The page contains javascripts, in which there is a long hex string - what I need ultimately. I tried disabling javascript and reloading the page. I still got the right page source. So javascript doesn't play trick here. It sounds getting such page source via curl should be just straight forward, right?

When I right click the request in Chrome Developer Tool -> Copy as cURL, and execute it in terminal, things turned nasty - I got a [CloudFlare security check page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JD2Dw.png). I reopened the page several times in Chrome Incognito mode. I swear never saw a CloudFlare security check in browser. I double checked the cURL command. It has user-agent set as well.

Here is what I tried so far:

- Manually compose curl command and fill headers from Chrome Developer Tool
- Sniff packages on an Android device, and use headers set on mobile browser
- Post request online from Postman Web

All gave me the same CloudFlare security check page.

The CloudFlare page says "Please enable cookies". I suspect if server in this way determined I was not calling from a browser. Following some threads, I tried to set -b/-c/-j flag with curl. Also no luck.

Here's more detailed steps what I've done:

1. Open Chrome Incognito mode
2. Open Developer Tool
3. Use Command+Shift+P (Mac) to open command menu
4. Type "disable javascript" and hit enter
5. Switch to Network tab
6. Open https://www.etoro.com/app/sv-iframe
7. Observe the request list - there should be only 1 request ([request screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHK2F.png) / [request screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmQi2.png) / [response body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqXp8.png) / [response cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3VOS.png))
8. Right click on the request -> Copy as cURL

Here's my curl command:

```
curl 'https://www.etoro.com/app/sv-iframe' \
  -H 'authority: www.etoro.com' \
  -H 'pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="89", "Chromium";v="89", ";Not A Brand";v="99"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: none' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  --compressed
```

The request itself I don't think it requires cookie, as page was able to be opened in Incognito mode. I anyways tried to set the response cookie together with the request. It doesn't help either.

```
-H 'cookie: __cfduid=d2edf...; TS01047baf=01d53...; __cf_bm=a3803...; __cflb=02Di3...'
```

Already spent whole evening on it but couldn't get it resolved. I appreciate any suggestions or help to get me thru it. I have a feeling that the actual fix would be fairly simple. The request has no cookie. Only thing to update is header. Maybe I didn't have correct header specified? Or some extra curl flag would help?

Comment: My browser devtools shows that when you visit that page, an AJAX POST happens.  It also shows 5 cookies being set.  You didn't show us any code, so it is hard to say if you are correctly receiving and using those cookies, or if you are replicating the POST, or even if that is necessary to get the hex you're after ...

Comment: You can probably fake the cookies, but curl isn't going to run any javascript that runs in the browser - it'll give whatever the server gives (for the UserAgent you provided) without any script processed.    Add -v to see the headers - might give some more ideas to play with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try https://github.com/lwthiker/curl-impersonate/tree/v0.5.4
what I get by curl-impersonate from https://www.etoro.com/app/sv-iframe :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Title</title></head><body><script>(function(){var js = "window['__CF$cv$params']={r:'7f0f24acce60352f'};_cpo=document.createElement('script');_cpo.nonce='',_cpo.src='/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/scripts/invisible.js',document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_cpo);";var _0xh = document.createElement('iframe');_0xh.height = 1;_0xh.width = 1;_0xh.style.position = 'absolute';_0xh.style.top = 0;_0xh.style.left = 0;_0xh.style.border = 'none';_0xh.style.visibility = 'hidden';document.body.appendChild(_0xh);function handler() {var _0xi = _0xh.contentDocument || _0xh.contentWindow.document;if (_0xi) {var _0xj = _0xi.createElement('script');_0xj.innerHTML = js;_0xi.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_0xj);}}if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {handler();} else if (window.addEventListener) {document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handler);} else {var prev = document.onreadystatechange || function () {};document.onreadystatechange = function (e) {prev(e);if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {document.onreadystatechange = prev;handler();}};}})();</script></body></html>
```

Comment: Huh, interesting tool. Thanks @xinyu. It does resolve my problem, at least for now. My issue was essentially hitting CloudFlare from curl, while in browser, it didn't mention anything related to CloudFlare at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is some obfuscated js eval code on that page, that is basically setting cookies or sending logs, digging a bit deeper, this is what ended up with:

```
 (function() {
    var s = '9a7xxx......';

    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, domain, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
        var cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue;
        if (domain) {
            cookie += ";" + "domain=" + domain;
        }
        cookie += ";" + expires + ";path=/";
        document.cookie = cookie;
    }

    function deleteCookie(cname, domain) {
        setCookie(cname, "", domain, 0);
    }
    var ta = ["window.callPhantom", "window.__nightmare", "window._phantom", "window.__webdriver_script_fn", "navigator.webdriver", "document.$cdc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_"];
    var re;
    try {
        re = [!!window.callPhantom, !!window.__nightmare, !!window._phantom, !!window.__webdriver_script_fn, !!navigator.webdriver, !!document.$cdc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_];
    } catch (err) {}
    if (re && re.indexOf(true) == -1) {
        setCookie("TMIS2", s, ".etoro.com", 14);
    } else {
        var resultsObj = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < ta.length; i++) {
            resultsObj[ta[i]] = re[i];
        }
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'https://etorologsapi.etoro.com/api/v2/monitoring?applicationIdentifier=JSCClient&LogEvents=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify([{
            ApplicationIdentifier: 'JSCClient',
            ApplicationVersion: '0.0.11',
            Level: "error",
            Message: "ClientSel",
            Results: resultsObj,
            Type: 'log'
        }]));
    }
 })();
```